# Encrypted data only readable by one program

Tags: program, encryption

I would like to know if an on-chain program could encrypt data, store it in an account and be the only one able to decrypt the data?
If it's possible, how to do this?

I feel it's not possible because you would have to, somehow, store the encryption key for the on-chain program to read it. But maybe there is a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"an on-chain program could encrypt data". This is not possible, the program binary is public, any input data to the program is public. As a result it is impossible to privately encrypt data in the program as you would have to reveal both the data to encrypt and like you said, the private key.